# Ansible task to copy SSH keys

Tags: ansible

I have a Cassandra cluster which contain 6 nodes and here is my Ansible inventory file:

```
[cassandra]
cassandra-01 ansible_host=192.168.2.10
cassandra-02 ansible_host=192.168.2.11
cassandra-03 ansible_host=192.168.2.12 
cassandra-04 ansible_host=192.168.2.13
cassandra-05 ansible_host=192.168.2.14
cassandra-06 ansible_host=192.168.2.15
```

I want to copy my SSH key from `cassandra-01` to all nodes in the cluster and I want to do that using Ansible task.

What is the best and idempotent way to achieve this?

P.S. I found this module [ssh-copy-id](https://github.com/ryankwilliams/ansible-ssh-copy-id) on Github, may be it will work?

Comment: Regarding the module in your question, it seems that according the documentation it is to "_authorize remote systems for passwordless SSH authentication_". So not exactly what your were looking for in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since I had a similar requirement in the past, I've found the following approach working

```
- name: Copy SSH key from node 01 to all others
  synchronize:
    src: "/tmp/ssh.key"
    dest: "/tmp/ssh.key"
    mode: push
  delegate_to: cassandra-01
  check_mode: no
  when: ( ansible_host != "cassandra-01" )
  tags: distribute_keys
```

mainly

- Use the module
  [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html), a `rsync` wrapper
- Let the task run on member server only (`when: "cassandra-01" not in ansible_host`)
- Delegate the task to the main node
- Push from main node to the member nodes

Comment: sorry, i mean that i want to make analogy of ssh-copy-id